# Объединения и указатели C++

Tags: c++, c++17

У нас есть следующее объединение:

```
union uni {
double* AsDouble;
char* AsChar;
}
```

Как в данном случае адекватно освободить память, если по окончанию работы мы не знаем какой указатель занесен.

Comment: Никак не освободить. Если вам непременно нужны два указателя, то используйте `::std::variant<::std::unique_ptr<double>, ::std::unique_ptr<char>>`.

Comment: если по окончанию работы Вам не известно, какой из указателей использовался, то как тогда во время работы все было? наверно где то был "флажок-признак". Вот значит его просто нужно переместить поближе к этой структуре. Если же это не так, тогда в коде явно проблема побольше.

Comment: Реально функции `free()` (внутри-то она вызывается) совершенно все равно с каким типом был связан адрес (указатель) в вашей программе. Поэтому используйте любой

Comment: Но там может быть массив. А ещё обращение к 'другой' переменной объединения, которая не была инициализирована - ub, хотя...